# Find the vertices of the edge of the polygon where line intersects using Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I have this function to get the intersection point of line and a polygon.
How to find the vertices of the polygon(red dots marked in the image) edge where the line intersects using shapely?
I have managed to find the nearest point using shapely `nearestPoint` function.

[image]

```
# get the intersection point.
def checkIntersection2(polyX, polyY, linePtX, linePtY):
    poly = LineString([(x, y) for x, y in zip(polyX, polyY)])
    line = LineString([(x, y) for x, y in zip(linePtX, linePtY)])
    intPoints = poly.intersection(line)
    return intPoints
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to iterate through the edges of the LinearRing of the polygon

```
from shapely.wkt import loads
lin = loads('LineString (289.63171806167395061 -200.22555066079294761, 380.69030837004402201 -65.28898678414094547)')
pol = loads('Polygon ((112.23259911894263041 -229.94933920704846742, 178.75726872246687549 -113.4132158590308137, 309.44757709251092592 -114.35682819383258391, 376.44405286343607031 -230.42114537444933831, 305.67312775330390195 -344.59823788546259493, 176.39823788546246419 -345.07004405286346582, 112.23259911894263041 -229.94933920704846742))')
# the LinearRing
from shapely.geometry import LineString
polin = LineString(list(pol.exterior.coords))
# intersection 
pt = polin.intersection(lin)
print(pt.wkt)
POINT (327.0268317294637 -144.8110298888352)
```

Now using [Determine if Shapely point is within a LineString/MultiLineString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295192) (using the answer of Mike T using the distance with an appropriate threshold  because there are floating point precision errors when finding a point on a line)

```
# iterate through the edges to determine if Shapely point is within
points = list(polin.coords)
for i,j in zip(points, points[1:]):
   if LineString((i,j)).distance(pt) < 1e-8:
       print(i,j)
(309.4475770925109, -114.35682819383258) (376.44405286343607, -230.42114537444934)
```

**Control**

[image]

Comment: I find this answer disappointing (well, not the answer, but the fact that Shapely does not have the capability of doing this without the need of a loop)... In order to find the intersection shapely already loops (efficiently I guess) through the edges of the polygons. It would cost nothing to add as output the segment of intersection. Looping through the edges again to find on which edge the intersection lies is almost like re-doing the search for the intersection point.